# If $A \subseteq B, $ then $f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: X \xrightarrow{} Y $and $A,B \subseteq Y. $ Show that if $A \subseteq B, $ then $f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$

I'm having a tough time getting started with this one so if someone could push me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You want to show that if $x\in f^{-1}(A) $ then $x\in f^{-1}(B)$.  So assume $x\in f^{-1}(A)$.  That means $f(x)\in A$.  Since $A\subseteq B\dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$x \in f^{-1}(A) \iff f(x) \in A.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x \in f^{-1}(A) \iff f(x) \in A \implies f(x) \in A\subseteq B \implies f(x) \in B \iff x \in f^{-1}(B).$$ 
Hence $f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$. Generally $f^{-1}$ respects set operation.